# How to ensure replicated and replicator couchdb's are at sync?

Tags: couchdb, replication

Couchdb is running on server1 and continuous-replication is being setup on server2 which will be in sync with server1. I am writing a script which will validate whether couchdb databases on both servers are at sync or not.

I can't validate using doc_count of each database since it won't take into account of individual files in each document of database. So, i thought of using update_seq of both databases but update_seq is different in both databases. Common observation is that update_seq is less in replicated database.

Is there anyway (or any attribute) with which i can validate whether databases on replicator and replicated couchdb are at sync?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread:  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.user/8802

Use a HTTP proxy to look at the replication traffic and it will make more sense. Use Fiddler or Charles.

You'll see the local database is looking at /_active_tasks and you can see how documents are replicated and get a better idea of how to monitor the status.